# count record from two tables which has no relation

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables `tbl_user1` and `tbl_user2` both are field name are same but there is no relation between that tables now I want to find total referred count from both table 
 for example...

```
tbl_user1
-----------------------
UID   | referenceBy      |  firstName  |   lastName  |  emailAddress
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | NULL             | aa1         | ab1         | aa1@email.com
2     | aa1@email.com    | aa2         | ab2         | aa2@email.com
3     | NULL             | aa3         | ab3         | aa3@email.com
4     | aa2@email.com    | aa4         | ab4         | aa4@email.com
5     | aa2@email.com    | aa5         | ab5         | aa5@email.com
6     | bb1@email.com    | aa6         | ab6         | aa6@email.com
7     | bb2@email.com    | aa7         | ab7         | aa7@email.com
8     | bb3@email.com    | aa8         | ab8         | aa8@email.com
9     | bb3@email.com    | aa9         | ab9         | aa9@email.com
```

and second one table is somthing like...

```
tbl_user2
-----------------------
UID   | referenceBy      |  firstName  |   lastName  |  emailAddress
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1     | NULL             | bb1         | bc1         | bb1@email.com
2     | bb1@email.com    | bb2         | bc2         | bb2@email.com
3     | NULL             | bb3         | bc3         | bb3@email.com
4     | bb3@email.com    | bb4         | bc4         | bb4@email.com
5     | bb2@email.com    | bb5         | bc5         | bb5@email.com
6     | bb1@email.com    | bb6         | bc6         | bb6@email.com
7     | aa2@email.com    | bb7         | bc7         | bb7@email.com
8     | aa3@email.com    | bb8         | bc8         | bb8@email.com
9     | bb5@email.com    | bb9         | bc9         | bb9@email.com
```

now, as you can see there is no relation between these two tables and I want result like following..

```
MAIN_RESULT_THAT_I_WANT
-----------------------
referenceEmail   |  referenceEmailCount 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
aa1@email.com    | 1
aa2@email.com    | 3
aa3@email.com    | 1
aa4@email.com    | 0
aa5@email.com    | 0
aa6@email.com    | 0
aa7@email.com    | 0
aa8@email.com    | 0
aa9@email.com    | 0
bb1@email.com    | 3
bb2@email.com    | 2
bb3@email.com    | 3
bb4@email.com    | 0
bb5@email.com    | 1
bb6@email.com    | 0
bb7@email.com    | 0
bb8@email.com    | 0
bb9@email.com    | 0
```

here in result all emailAddress of all user and total of how many user(s)  registered by that particular emailAddress.

Comment: okk, there are two types of user and i make separate table for both, now both user has functionality to invite users and invited user can be of any type. so, here tbl_user1's emailAddress can be referenceBy of tbl_user1 and tbl_user2 same way tbl_user2's emailAddress can be referenceBy of tbl_user1 and tbl_user2..

Comment: select emailAddress, count(*)  as referenceEmailCount from (
select * from table_1
union all 
select * from table_2

) as t
group by t.emailAddress,t.referenceBy

Comment: If the schema is identical for both user types, it might be better to add them to the same table with an added `user_type` column to specify what type of user each record represents.

Comment: @chiraglathiya, if you think any of the answers have a good solution please mark with accepted. Otherwise please specify why the answers are not correct or not complete.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that the result you want is just copy and pasted since it seems inaccurate. Like HoneyBadger says it is strange that aa6 is missing and still in the result, that indicates you have another list you are not telling us about? Or you just write the result in notepad...

If you just want a list of emails and count this will work:

```
select referenceBy, count(1) as referenceEmailCount from (
  select referenceBy from tbl_user1
  union all
  select referenceBy from tbl_user2
) as t
group by referenceBy
```

Otherwise give us more info if this is not what you need.

Comment: Good answer. You do know, however, that `count(1)` means: "for every row evaluate whether 1 is null and count the row in case it is not"? It results in the same value as `count(*)` which simply means "count rows", but may give the DBMS additional work to do (if the optimizer surprisingly doesn't see through this). I suggest to use the straight-forward `count(*)` anyway when you only want to count rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since the schema is same for 2 tables so you can perform `union` to get combined results and can perform an outer query to get the total count.

```
select referenceEmail, count(*)  as referenceEmailCount from (
select * from table1
union all 
select * from table2

) as alias 
group by alias.referenceEmail
```